# javascript clock converting real time to only seconds

Tags: javascript, clock

I'm relatively new to javascript, and have been trying to figure out a way to create a clock (which takes a bit explaining, please bear with me):

I'm trying to create a javascript clock where the clock follows real time, and then calculates how many seconds have gone by since midnight (at which point the clock resets). Then i want to be able to define what one second is in milliseconds, i.e. change how long one second lasts.

My plan is for it to be a working clock that counts 200.000 "seconds" in exactly 24 hours (if each "second" lasts 0,432 real seconds this will happen).

Any tips? All help would be greatly appreciated.

PS. for those interested I am doing a paper on time theory where I argue that clocks should follow the metric system and that a day should have 20 hours, each hour should last 100 minutes, and each minute should last 100 seconds. By doing this the clock is merely a kind of timer that counts to 200.000 from midnight to midnight.

PPS. if anything in unclear I will try to explain this in more depth.

Comment: Look at the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) method.

Comment: Ok - so what's your question? You going to need to use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object to get the current time, get the hour, minute and seconds from it, convert to seconds then convert to your format. Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) to make the code update as often as you want. Note: don't expect `setInterval` to be accurate. I.e, if you ask it to update every 1000 milliseconds, it will drift, so always get the real time with `Date.now()`

Comment: @MattBurland Hive mind

Answer (score 2):

You want the setInterval function which you can specify to fire every 432 milliseconds.

```
secondTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
    // do stuff in here
},432);
```

As others have mentioned this isn't the most accurate timer, so you'll want to use the Date object to synchronize to the actual time.

Answer (score 2):

Dates in Javascript are actually a number that counts the amount of milisseconds since a given fixed date. So if you have any date in Javascript, you can use its [`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method to see that number. The documentation in the link is a little more in depth than my short description here.

So if you want to see how many seconds have elaped between today, 0 hours and today, right now, you can use the following code:

```
var now = new Date(); // a new Date initialized without parameter defaults to current time

// Initializing with just year, month and day will set the time of the day to 00:00:00
var today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());

var milisseconds = now.getTime() - today.getTime();
```

Now all you have to do is divide the `milisseconds` variable by 1000 and you'll have the amount of "imperial" seconds. From then on you can convert to your "metric" seconds as you wish.

This will do for convertion... Now, to get Javascript to do something at given intervals, you can use the global function `setInterval`, like in **Mordred's answer**. I'm quoting here, but kudos and +1 to him:

```
timer = setInterval(function () {
    // do stuff in here
}, 432); // 432 is an arbitrary value, this will fire once every 432 milisseconds.
```

Do check the documentation [for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) and [for `SetTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).

And as Matt said in the comments for the question, the timed events in Javascript may not always fire accurately at the time intervals you set - there are other things involved, you may do some research on that - so do check the current time when the event was fired by initializing a new `Date` object. Notice that:

```
var x = Date.now();
```

Is a shorthand for:

```
var d = new Date();
var x = d.getTime();
```

Working with dates in Javascript might be a little awkward for beginners... do notice that some method names and properties of the Date object might be misleading. Months are 0-based,  and `getDay` will return the day of the week and not of the month, so make sure to read some documentation there. Other than that, good luck and happy coding!

Comment: He stated that his metric "seconds" aren't actual seconds, but are .432 of a real second, which was why I specified 432 as the interval time.